# How can I modify the disk space output of Logwatch?

Tags: logwatch

I've got logwatch sending me reports every day and part of that report is a disk space analysis. I was wondering how I could modify the disk space script to put emphasis on disks that are greater than 90% full. Is there a way to do that without modifying the core of Logwatch?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out you can modify the disk usage script located at `/usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/zz-disk_usage`. I captured the output of the `df` command logwatch was using and parsed it to look for percentages over a certain amount.